# Is solution to this question partly incorrect, i.e. does the solution contain a typo?

Tags: classical-mechanics

This is another old O level applied mathematics problem regarding moments. It reads as follows:

A rod $PQ$ is $5 ft.$ long. When a $1 lb.$ mass is hung from $P$ and a $3 lb.$ mas is hung from $Q$, the rod balances at a point $42 in.$ from $P$. When the masses are interchanged, the rod balances at a point $22 in.$ from $P$. Calculate the mass of the rod and the distance of its centre of gravity from $P$.

Solution gives:

$mass = 21 lb.$
$dist. from$ $P = 3 ft.$

I am able to get the distance of $3 ft.$ but am getting the mass of the rod to be $2 lb.$ This seems to be a little light but as I can not obtain the answer for mass given as solution, I am wondering if there is a typo in the book.

If anyone can offer any assistance I would be very grateful.

Not very good at computer code so hope this attachment helps.

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

Many thanks for any help or advice once again.

Comment: It would help if you showed us your calculations.

Comment: Yes please do. There is a lot of arithmetic/algebra here and we should not have to reinvent any more wheels than necessary.

Comment: Sounds like this will not work.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Apologies. I am not sure if there is another way to show you calculations other than leaving a comment but here goes.
Let x represent distance of centre of gravity from Q, W the weight of the rod and R the reaction in the two instances given.
Taking moments about Q gave the following two equations:
W*x + 1*5 = 3R/2     (1)
W*x + 3*5 = 19R/6   (2)
also up forces = down forces so R = 4 + W  (3)
(3) into (1) and (2) respectively gives:
(2*x - 3)*W = 2        (4)
(19 - 6*x)*W = 14    (5)
rearranging and equating (4) and (5) gives my result where x is distance from Q.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Hello again. I have added an attachment to show my working. If you can see a mistake in my reasoning then I would be extremely grateful if you could let me know. I've been at this for some time now but can not see an error. Many thanks.

Comment: It is out of focus!

Comment: I'm afraid your picture is illegible.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will try and take the picture again.

Comment: Ironically, your very own picture ends with the conclusion $W=21$. Just look at it! (Please don't edit it out -- it is a perfect mistake.)

Comment: @TonyK It’s actually the l from pound abbreviation ie lb, I just missed a little off when taking the picture - not too good with technology I’m afraid. However, I agree it does look like I’ve given the answer of 21 so I will leave alone and not edit. Many thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a misprint. I did the calculations (independently of your illegible working!), and I got a mass of 2 lb.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried to upload new pictures if they help at all. Once again, many thanks for taking the time to reply.